# GoogleCode: How to enable gzip compression?

Tags: google-code

I have js file in googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Js/my.js .

But page speed validator says "Enable gzip compression", "Specify a Vary: Accept-Encoding header"

What property should I use to enable gzip compression and "Specify a Vary: Accept-Encoding header" for my.js ?

Comment: enabling gzip compression is done at the webserver config, not in your javascript.

for Apache, for example, you can leverage mod_deflate.  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html

Comment: I know, but this is for local files, such as myserver.com/my.js. I have js in google code server  googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Js/my.js  . So I need to use properties for this js. I don't know what properties.